# C# - Issue with lock and StreamWrite (Multi-threading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task, streamwriter

I created a simple Logger class that uses StreamWriter to append text to a log file. The main program is a task scheduler that executes tasks asynchronously and writes in the log file if the execution was successful or not. 
The program reads from a database and adds tasks to a list and the ExecuteAll() methods execute asynchronously every task in that list. If any step in the reading\writing to the database or task execution goes wrong- I use Logger.Error().

When I Run the program everything goes fine but when I add Thread.Sleep(5000) to every task to simulate connecting to an API I get an **IOExecption**:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'Log.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

**The Logger Class:**

```
    public class Logger
    {
        const string filePath = @"Log.txt";
        private static readonly object writerLock = new object();
        public static string Info(string log)
        {
            string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateTimeFormat) + " | INFO | " + log;
            lock (writerLock)
            {
                using (StreamWriter logToFile = File.AppendText(filePath))
                {
                    logToFile.WriteLine(logMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
                }
            }
            return logMessage;
        }
        public static string Error(string log)
        {
            string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateTimeFormat) + " | ERROR | " + log;
            lock (writerLock)
            {
                using (StreamWriter logToFile = File.AppendText(filePath))
                {
                    logToFile.WriteLine(logMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
                }
            }
            return logMessage;
        }
    }
```

**The async method:**

```
public void ExecuteJob(Job job)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                job.Execute(); // Executes: Log.Info("Job Executed.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error($"Couldn't Execute Job #{job.jobId}: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                DbManager.UpdateJobInTable(job.jobId);
                jobs.Remove(job);

            }
        }
        //Execute all jobs
        public async void ExecuteAll()
        {
            if (!jobs.Any())
                return;
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (Job job in jobs.ToArray())
            {
                tasks.Add(
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        ExecuteJob(job); 
                    })
                );
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
```

Why does the lock doesn't prevent from threads to enter the StreamWriter when a thread already is using it? Why when I run the program without Thread.Sleep(5000) it seems to work fine?

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say that the error is "multiple processes"?

Comment: There are many many existing log packages that will do exactly as you want without all the issues you are hitting (and will hit in the future).  Don't reinvent the wheel !

Comment: @Neil  Thanks, Neil. I agree with you and I will use existing log package in the future. But I want to understand what was wrong for learning purposes.

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited the post so you can see the exact exception message. Thanks.

Comment: @RonD Is there other code (except Logger) that reads/writes data to the `Log.txt`? Are you able to ensure that other instances of your program are not running when an error occurs?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev No. I made sure only the Logger class reads/write to Log.txt. But, there are several methods that call the Logger methods. everything goes through Logger though.

Comment: I have no idea about the cause of the problem. I suggest though that you declare the class `Logger` as `static`, to ensure that it contains only static members. Also, as a side note, [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: @RodD, was not able to reproduce this issue. This code should work, make sure that ou have only one instance running of your app and this file is not accessed by any other application, or any other code in your app.

Comment: Could you try using the simpler [`File.AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext) instead of the `File.AppendText`, to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Not seem to work.

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? Use the existing [ReadWriterLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netcore-3.1) to support multi-threaded writing. I'm also sure that libraries for multi-threaded logging also exist.

Comment: Another side note: I hope that the collection `jobs` is thread-safe, because it is mutated from multiple threads without synchronization.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias jobs is List<Job> and I use it cast it to array in the foreach so I can remove jobs from the list. How would you make it thread - safe as you said?

Comment: You can either use a [concurrent collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) that is thread-safe by design (like the [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) for example) and use only its specialized API (forget about LINQ methods like `Any`), or keep using a thread-unsafe `List` but protect every access to it using a `lock`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code (well, other than inventing a logging system unnecessarily); the locking is correct. My first guess would be that your code is running into an anti-virus program; some of them like to examine files that have just been written.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks. Actually I hoped there is something wrong with my code so I could know how to fix it. Can you please review my Execute All() and ExecuteJob() methods?

Comment: @RonD: SO isn't a [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, I'll echo what others have observed: the safety of these methods depends on what type `jobs` is.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that lock doesn't work with async processes:

https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/

> The lock keyword can only be used to synchronize synchronous code. From MSDN:
>
> An await expression cannot occur in the body of a synchronous function, in a query expression, in the block of a lock statement, or in an unsafe context.

Comment: You can't write `await ...` inside lock block, but you can call `lock` inside async method and it should work as with usual threads..

Comment: @Neil I tried to do the change to semaphore as explained in the article, same exception pops up.